# Export AsciiMathML equations to Excel Format

Tags: php, excel, transform, mathml, spreadsheetml

I have to export a list of mathematical questions which have AsciiMathML notation to an Excel spreadsheet and I want to show the equations properly. My code is written in PHP and I want to create the Excel file on the server side and make it available for download.

I found that there are number of libraries which are in JavaScript to convert AsciiMathML to images, such as http://dlippman.imathas.com/asciimathtex/AMT.html

But what I need is to convert the equations to images or most preferably to Excel equations on the server side with PHP. Is there anyone aware of any libraries that I can use? I really appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [spreadsheetML stylesheet](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2005/01/create_excels_s.html) to convert the MathML to Excel, using the `transformToXML` function like this:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load($file_name);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('convert.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$result = $proc->transformToXML($xml)
```

**References**

- [Create Excel's SpreadsheetML using XSLT](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2005/01/create_excels_s.html)